# Displaying data from rest API using jQuery

Tags: jquery, rest

I'm trying to return some data and display it on my page... but not sure exactly what to do here. I do get an object back just not sure how to iterate it on the page.

```
  <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Release"/>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        alert("button");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "http://ebird.org/ws1.1/data/notable/geo/recent?lng=-110.926479&lat=32.221743&dist=2&back=5&maxResults=500&detail=simple&locale=en_US&fmt=json",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#div1").html(result);
                alert("success" + result);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Local error callback.");
            },
            complete: function () {
                alert("Local completion callback.");
            }
        });
    }); 

});

<div id="div1"></div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are u able to get data in `result`?because it shows me an err

Comment: @debin : Yes, I tested his REST call. You have some data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a each loop:

```
var result =[{"obsDt":"2016-02-23 10:15","lng":-110.9235907,"locName":"Reid Park","obsValid":true,"comName":"Summer Tanager","obsReviewed":true,"sciName":"Piranga rubra","locationPrivate":false,"howMany":1,"lat":32.2102866,"locID":"L227274"}]

$.each(result,function(i,v){
  alert(v.comName)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,
You got a JSON response for you request. 
How you display it, is eternally up to you. JSON is data, not layout or display information.
I would suggest a MVVM framework like knockout.js. (Don’t ever go with Angulrajs, you’ll be lost).
You can “display” your results in about 5-6 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the array by object name like below.

```
 <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Release"/>  


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        alert("button");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "http://ebird.org/ws1.1/data/notable/geo/recent?lng=-110.926479&lat=32.221743&dist=2&back=5&maxResults=500&detail=simple&locale=en_US&fmt=json",
            success: function (result) {

            console.log(result);
            console.log(result[0].obsDt);
            console.log(result[0].lat);
            console.log(result[0].lng);
            console.log(result[0].comName);

            $("#div1").html(result[0].obsDt);

                alert("success" + result);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Local error callback.");
            },
            complete: function () {
                alert("Local completion callback.");
            }
        });
    }); 

});

<div id="div1"></div>
```